# Gnome3 session logout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, gnome3, logout

With gnome 2 there was the possibility to logout from a session by executing

```
gnome-session-save --force-logout
```

Unfortunately this gnome-session-save doesn't exist in Gnome3. Is there a different way to do it or am I just missing a packet?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-core installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
gnome-session-quit --logout --force --no-prompt
```